# Not able to connect to Remote host

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-5.1

Hi I am trying to connect to a remote host using Powershell but getting the following error:

`New : The term 'New' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

What I am trying to do is to connect to a remote host and find a log file. But the issue is I cannot even connect to the host.

`$host = New-PSSession -ComputerName a.b.c.d(IP)`

Also tried,

`$RemoteServer = "a.b.c.d" $Username = "xyz\abc" $Password = "abc"`

`$sess = New -PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteServer -Credential $Username -Password $Password`

Still getting the same error message. I am running Powershell as an admin. In the second method that I tried I had to put in the password, is there a way that can be avoided because that means it needs to be changed everytime the password gets updated. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest looking into `Get-Help` to better understand PowerShells grammar. There is no `-Password` parameter for `New-PSSession`, and there also cant be any spaces betweem the verb-noun naming converntion for cmdlets. Create a credential object from the `PSCrendential` class and pass it as an argument: `$creds = [PSCredential]::new($username,$password)`; this is using the type accelerator for `PSCredential` so all that's needed is to provide it as the argument for `-Credential`.

Comment: adding to this^, you need to convert the password to a secure string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after New

The command is New-PSSession without space

Comment: Now getting the error, ``New-PSSession : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Password'.
At xyz.ps1:5 char:73
+ ... n -ComputerName $RemoteServer -Credential $Username -Password $Passwo ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-PSSession], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSSessionCommand
 
``

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: While you're correct, such information is better provided in the form of a _comment_. If this turns out to be the only issue, the question should be closed as "not reproducible or caused by a typo".

Comment: @mklement0 still having the issue. The comment has the error message that I am still getting

Comment: @ChristinaEvans, understood, but Abraham has already addressed the follow-up error in his comments.